# Unable to store an std::type_info object in an std::tuple

Tags: c++, generics, c++17, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I'm trying to initialize a tuple (using `std::make_tuple`), and I want to store an std::type_info in it as well, but I don't know why for some reason this simple looking piece of code doesn't compile.

I tried running the following code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <any>

int main()
{
    
    std::tuple<std::type_info, int, std::any> tpl = std::make_tuple(typeid(float), 1, "Hello");
    
    const auto&[type, num, anyval] = tpl;
    std::cout<<type.name()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<num<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::any_cast<const char*>(anyval)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I only omit storing the first value (ie. type info) and create only `std::tuple<int, std::any>` there doesn't seem to be any problem, but this attempt fails. How to get around it, as I've to store the `std::type_info` object anyhow.

Comment: "*this simple looking piece of code doesn't compile.*" What compile errors are you getting?

Comment: @NicolBolas here you go: https://godbolt.org/z/ETPrqG1eb, pages of errors. I personally don't know how to fix it, but maybe it'll help you help him!

Comment: @Blindy: You should put the errors into your question.

Comment: It threw a lot of errors. It was very dirty to read to be honest. That's why I didn't post that here.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that `std::type_info` do not have ANY constructors. No copy, no move or default constructors. So you can't copy this value. You can get only reference of it.

You can use `std::reference_wrapper` as a workarund:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<const std::type_info>, int, std::any> tpl = std::make_tuple(std::cref(typeid(float)), 1, "Hello");

    const auto& [type, num, anyval] = tpl;
    std::cout << type.get().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::any_cast<const char*>(anyval) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/czobc3h57

As point out by `StoryTeller` there is [std::type_index](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) to address this issue in nicer way:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::tuple<std::type_index, int, std::any> tpl = std::make_tuple(std::type_index(typeid(float)), 1, "Hello");

    const auto& [type, num, anyval] = tpl;
    std::cout << type.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::any_cast<const char*>(anyval) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/z5dv8Wf86

Comment: `std::type_index` would make a better wrapper. That's its whole point of being.

Comment: "Unslander Monica" is a protest against SO in general, it's not a username. Their username is `StoryTeller` lol

Comment: @Blindy I have no idea what is this protest is,  thanks for catching that :).

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked this, but now I've a solution which might be even better.

I skipped storing `std::type_info` (or `std::type_index`) at all. The third type (`std::any`) contains an `std::type_info` for the type it is enclosing, so storing it twice wouldn't be a good thing anyways.

Although the standard library does provide std::type_index which I didn't knew but came across while researching for this a bit.